# Is it okay to put hooks inside a confirm dialog?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the documentation for Hooks, it mentions that you shouldn't use hooks inside of conditionals, whether they be for loops or if statements. However, I need to put hooks inside of a confirm dialog to in order to confirm with an user that they want to close the modal they are currently working in, and that goes against the hooks documentation so I'm concerned with the side effects of it, despite the fact it works fine. Here's a rough example of the logic(it's a bit buggier than my actual usecase, because the modal isn't showing up in codesandbox, but that's not the issue haha)

https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-inside-a-confirm-dgvxp

Comment: You are not calling a hook in a condition here. Your hook is called at the top level of your component. You are just using the updater function conditionally which is provided by your hook.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in your code in accordance with the doc. You're free to go !